# What are the well known protocols that offer perfect forward secrecy?

Tags: protocol-design, tls, ssh, forward-secrecy, ipsec

As far as I know these are the well known protocols that offer PFS

- TLS/SSL (with DHE-RSA, DHE-DSS, ECDHE-RSA or ECDHE-ECDSA)
- SSH ([RFC4253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253))
- OTR ([Protocol Version 3 Spec](https://otr.cypherpunks.ca/Protocol-v3-4.0.0.html))
- IPsec (with IKEv1 and IKEv2) ([RFC 2412](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2412))

Are there any other well known protocols? Have any of these been shown to be insecure?

Comment: One terminology nit: IPsec (RFC4301) itself doesn't provide perfect forward secrecy, as IPsec just handles the packet encryption (and other packet handling); perfect forward secrecy is a property of the keying protocol.  Hence, it is IKE (both IKEv1 and IKEv2) that offers PFS; however IPsec keyed with a different protocol might not.

Comment: @poncho Thanks for the clarification. I will edit it.